# ASP.NET GET request

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

Why does an ASP.NET button (by default) make POST request? Is it possible to alter this behavior? I need to have my button make a GET request.

I tried to set the HTTP data transfer method to GET by doing this --

```
Dim context As HttpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current
Dim request As HttpRequest = context.Request
request.RequestType = "GET"
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Because button click does postback; which means a post request to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's possible to make a straightforward ASP.NET button send a GET request. ASP.NET stores a ton of information on the page and returns this on the post back -- the view state. This is probably too much for a get.

You can easily create a link that will do a GET request with an asp:hyperlink tag. You could create an HTML button object that has onclick behavior that does windows.location= to effectively act like a GET.

You cannot create another form on your page that does a GET, because an ASP.NET page can only have one form.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is caused by a form with `method="post"`. You can change this, by using

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="name" />
   <input type="button" value="Save" />
</form>
```

This will make a `GET` request. Default is `GET`. I don't know why your request was being a `POST` but the only behaviour that might cause this would be the fact that the form your button is residing in is having `method="post"`. This way, the request being made is now a POST one.

Change that thing, and you will get the output that you're wanting.

Comment: But in my case, I have an aspx page and on button click the respective function is called in my aspx.vb code behind page. How would it be possible to call some function in my aspx.vb page if I use the <form> tag?

Comment: But the OP is asking about within ASP.NET. I don't think you can just slap a "method=GET" on the form tag.

Comment: I think you're using Web Forms, and the form you're having is set to be sending `method="post"`. You can check that in the page you're having.

Comment: @Jay, you cannot and you shouldn't. Because `method="get"` is the default behaviour of a form too.

Comment: Yes, it's a Web Form. Can you please specify where I can check for the default behavior of GET/POST?

Comment: Inside the `form` element itself. You might be able to see the `method="post"` there. That is causing this behaviour. Since Web Forms is a Form itself, they cause the navigation to look like a simple HTTP request so they use the post method.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify method in the form, e.g.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="get">

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

</form>
```

But this will pass everything in querystring - including ViewState, you will see things like

```
...Default.aspx?__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKMjA0OTM4MTAwNGRkWg%2FUFN%2FiSKnn0PXnaxicZZP%2BkRo%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWAgKZlprMBQKM54rGBlcwa3uNV3%2BKkm7r8IYXTcNXsc1W&Button1=Button
```

So I do not think you want this. Also querystring length is very limited comparing to post body. If you want to use GET to pass something in a querystring - use [HyperLink control and its NavigateURL property.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.navigateurl(v=vs.110).aspx)